# PhpStorm: partially different font in editor

Tags: fonts, configuration, phpstorm, jetbrains-ide, phpstorm-2018.2

This is what happened on last install:

[image]

`private`, `function`, `return`, `if`, `foreach`, `namespace`, `class`, `use` are in different font then the rest of the file - actually everything orange in Darcula. And the completion popup/window.

I'm rocking this configuration:

```
PhpStorm 2018.2.5
Build #PS-182.4892.16, built on October 11, 2018
Licensed to PhpStorm Evaluator
Expiration date: November 28, 2018
JRE: 1.8.0_152-release-1248-b8 amd64
JVM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o
Linux 4.19.0-041900rc8-lowlatency
```

System fonts are set like this:

[image]

Editor like this:

[image]

Comment: Try different font (at least to see how it looks there)? Based on screenshot all those words are using **bold** style/font weight. Maybe it's something to do with the actual font files (e.g. try refreshing them / clear cache etc, sorry, not a Linux user myself)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok, @LazyOne was right, it was font error! Monospaced looked so similar to what I was used to - which was DejaVu Sans Mono

Now everything looks as it should. thx!